# Create criteria without active transaction in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring and Hibernate, and am ideally looking at spring to manage my transactions. However I am getting an error - 'Calling method 'createCriteria' is not valid without an active transaction (Current status: NOT_ACTIVE)' exception.

This is how my hibernate.cfg.xml looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://abc.def:1111/db_name?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">200</property>
        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
                

        <!-- dbcp connection pool configuration -->
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">80</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>
        <mapping class="com.mypackage.com.model.ABC" />
        .... //mapping classes

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my HibernateUtils.java

```
public class HibernateUtils {
    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                // Create registry
                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

                // Create MetadataSources
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

                // Create Metadata
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

                // Create SessionFactory
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added this in application.properties

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean> 

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"  />
```

Finally my DB calls look like this:

```
Session session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ABC.class); //Error line
ABC obj = (ABC) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId", userId)).uniqueResult();
if(obj == null) return null;
return obj;
```

My pom looks like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>            
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. Ditch that ugly `HibernateUtils`, ditch the `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Inject the `SessionFactory` which is created by `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. And no you should really use a transaction, if you don't you would need to use `openSession` instead of `getCurrentSession` which would also make you need to manage the session lifecycle (properly close it etc.) with a transaction all of that is managed for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum without the hibernate.cfg.xml how are we going to set the properties in that case? Could you please share some example to help me understand? Thanks

Comment: Through the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. You don't need the connection stuff, you shouldn't be setting the `current.context` stuff. The datasource is your connection pool. Everything else are already properties on that class.